# How to set up Apache/MySql/Django environment for development

Tags: python, apache2, mysql, web-development

I've only been able to find tutorials to set up Apache/MySql/Django on servers, but I'd like to set up an environment on my machine for development. Does anyone have any good tutorials or suggestions? Thanks in advanced!

Edit: If there isn't a good one, let's team up and write one!

Comment: Have you tried one of those tutorials for the Server edition on the Desktop? What is it that doesn't work on the Desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hosting a web server locally, I would suggest that you grab [PyCharm Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/), which simplifies the process;  Develop with the built-in server locally, and [deploy](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/deployment.html) to your 'production' server when you are ready.

Installing MySql is simpler, you can use

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Ah, I've downloaded PyCharm but stepped away from it in favor of Eclipse and PyDev. I'll give it another go tonight. Thanks for the suggestions!